# how to use long in string methods like charAt in java?

Tags: java, string, charat

how to use long in string methods like charAt in java??

```
String s="google";
long i=0;
System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
```

Comment: You simply cast it to int `s.charAt((int) i)`

Comment: Do you have a String with over Integer.MAX_VALUE characters?

Comment: no. is big that's why using long

Comment: How the answer is no if the reason you use long is because you believe int could be not enough xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum Integer value in Java is: 2,147,483,647. Which means that for `s.charAt(i)`, `i` can have a max value of 2,147,483,647 (2 billion)

Will you really have a string having more than 2 billion bytes of length?
`int` is fairly enough.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Integer.MaX_VALUE` is `2,147,483,647` (2 mld). Even if you'd use ANSI encoding, string with this many characters would have almost 2 gigabytes! With UTF-8 encoding that'd be 8 gigabytes!

So an integer is perfectly fine for representing character's position within a string, and If you want to get that position by long, just cast it.

```
string.charAt((int) i);
```